# VB.net choose multiple random items from arraylist only once

Tags: vb.net, function

So I'm trying to make a function where I can input a arraylist and the function randomly picks X amount of items from that arraylist and outputs the result to a new arraylist. This I've got working, the problem I'm having is that after one of the items is picked by the randomize, it's still there which means that it can be picked again. Here is the code I got so far

```
Dim RandomGeneratorMulti As New ArrayList()
    Dim resultMulti As New ArrayList()

        RandomGeneratorMulti.Add("Happy")
        RandomGeneratorMulti.Add("Sad")
        RandomGeneratorMulti.Add("Smart")
        RandomGeneratorMulti.Add("Intelegt")
        RandomGeneratorMulti.Add("Stupid")
        RandomGeneratorMulti.Add("Ugly")

        ChooseMulti("5", RandomGeneratorMulti)
        TraitsListBox.Items.AddRange(resultMulti.ToArray)
```

Here is the function

```
 Function ChooseMulti(ByVal Numbers As Integer, ByVal Alist As ArrayList) As ArrayList

        Dim rnd = New Random()


        For i As Integer = 1 To Numbers

            resultMulti.Add(Alist.Item(rnd.Next(0, Alist.Count)))


        Next
        Return resultMulti

    End Function
```

All help is much appreciated :)

Comment: ArrayLists are dead. They exist for backwards compatibility with old code. Use Generic List(Of T)s instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `List(Of String)` rather than an `ArrayList`, but I have written the code below using `ArrayList` so that it's closer to the original.

You can remove the items that you pick from the list:

```
Function ChooseMulti(ByVal numbers As Integer, ByVal Alist As ArrayList) As ArrayList
  Dim resultMulti As New ArrayList()
  Dim rnd = New Random()
  For i As Integer = 1 To numbers
    Dim index As Integer = rnd.Next(Alist.Count)
    resultMulti.Add(Alist.Item(index))
    Alist.RemoveAt(index)
  Next
  Return resultMulti
End Function
```

Note: As you are returning the list from the function, you should get the return value and put in the `resultMulti` variable, and not change the variable from inside the function:

```
resultMulti = ChooseMulti(5, RandomGeneratorMulti)
```

Another method is to shuffle the list (using [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)) and then take the first items:

```
Function ChooseMulti(ByVal numbers As Integer, ByVal Alist As ArrayList) As ArrayList
  Dim resultMulti As New ArrayList()
  Dim rnd = New Random()
  For i As Integer = Alist.Count - 1 to 1 Step -1
    Dim index = rnd.Next(i + 1)
    Dim temp As String = Alist(i)
    Alist(i) = Alist(index)
    Alist(index) = temp
  Next
  For i As Integer = 0 To numbers - 1
    resultMulti.Add(Alist.Item(i))
  Next
  Return resultMulti
End Function
```

Yet another approach is to pick numbers from the list from start to end. That way there can't be duplicates and the original list is left unchanged, but a side effect is that the picked items have the same order as in the original list:

```
Function ChooseMulti(ByVal numbers As Integer, ByVal Alist As ArrayList) As ArrayList
  Dim resultMulti As New ArrayList()
  Dim rnd = New Random()
  Dim index As Integer = 0
  While numbers > 0
    If rnd.Next(Alist.Count - index) < numbers Then
      resultMulti.Add(Alist.Item(index))
      numbers -= 1
    EndIf
    index += 1
  Wend
  Return resultMulti
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly was I was looking for :)

Comment: @kagstrom2100: I tested all three functions, and I don't get any exception. Are you trying to pick more items than there are in the list?

Comment: Yeah, never mind, I didn't notice that my RandomGeneratorMulti arraylist only had one item :) Thanks anyways